# Firebase Database rules when linking accounts

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have Android application that stores data either using anonymous sign in or using logged account.

Problem is when user wants to convert data created as anonymous user into logged account. I linked both anonymous and signed in account with success but I'm getting

```
SyncTree: Listen at /currentSession/xxx-AnonymousLoginUserId-xx failed: DatabaseError: This client does not have permission to perform this operation
```

I suspect that it is because of access rules but I have no idea how to specify them to tell Firebase that it should accept both accounts.

Rules look like

```
{
  "rules": {
    "currentSession": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.provider === 'anonymous'",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.provider === 'anonymous'"
      }
    ...
},
```

Now when I'm thinking about the issue I'm sure that `|| auth.provider='anonymous'` is wrong but I'm sharing to help you with diagnosis.

BTW: Everything works well in case rules are

```
 {
    "rules": {
      "currentSession": {
        "$uid": {
           ".write": true,
            ".read": true
          }
        ...
 },
```

but I'm not happy with so weak rules

EDIT 1: Syntax error with auth.provider='anonymous' is probably not the cause (I didn't copy it, I just typed it from my memory).

EDIT 2: Please note `currentSession : { "$uid" : {` ... I realized that most likely the problem is that `auth.uid` is only one variable but in case of linked accounts it should be probably set of uids. Any idea?

Comment: With regard to your edits, you may need to give more detail about how exactly you're linking accounts and some code for what you're doing in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax error here is that the `anonymous` part of your rule should be:

```
auth.provider == 'anonymous'
```

As can be seen in [examples here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#auth) a double = to compare rather than a single one(assignment).

However further than that I'm not completely sure if you need the anonymous bit at all.

If the flow is someone starting as an anonymous user then converting that to a new signed in account instead using the [linkWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account) functionality, the Uid remains the same throughout. In that case, simply checking that the uid matches would be enough as it wouldn't matter if the account was currently anonymous or not.

Comment: Ok, I'll doublecheck. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my original question, the problem is probably with data structure and fact that `auth.uid` has only one value but I would expect that it contains two uids in case I linked anonymous and logged in account.

Comment: Uid can't be the same if you start anonymous and later switch to existing account with already assigned uid.